# Python random.shuffle() returning different results when function passed in

Tags: python

I'm trying to unit test some code that makes use of `random.shuffle(a, func)`. In order to keep the ordering deterministic, I pass in a func defined as:

```
def func():
  return 0.1
```

what's strange is that the list seems to still get shuffled.

```
import random

def func():
  return 0.1

a = ['c', 'good', 'b', 'hello', 'a']
random.shuffle(a, func)
print(a)

random.shuffle(a, func)
print(a)

random.shuffle(a, func)
print(a)
```

output:

```
['good', 'b', 'hello', 'a', 'c']
['b', 'hello', 'a', 'c', 'good']
['hello', 'a', 'c', 'good', 'b']
```

What's going on here?

Comment: As an aside, _DeprecationWarning: The *random* parameter to shuffle() has been deprecated since Python 3.9 and will be removed in a subsequent version._

Comment: @tdelaney: it's always good to [link to the `random.shuffle()` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random%20shuffle#random.shuffle), for the latest updates in 3.10, 3.11 and beyond.

Comment: Stop using the 2nd arg in `random.shuffle(a, func)`, that signature is going to break in future when it's deprecated, so stop using it today. Given that we can assume `random.shuffle()` builtin itself works, what is it that your unittest is supposed to test?

Comment: Also, your title is misleading. `random.shuffle()` returns different results when it's called multiple times, that's exactly its intended behavior(!), it doesn't matter whether you pass a second arg. Please see the 66 existing Q&A for [*`random.shuffle` random argument*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=random.shuffle+random+argument)

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the array after each shuffle:

```
import random

def func():
  return 0.1

a = ['c', 'good', 'b', 'hello', 'a']
random.shuffle(a, func)
print(a)

a = ['c', 'good', 'b', 'hello', 'a']
random.shuffle(a, func)
print(a)

a = ['c', 'good', 'b', 'hello', 'a']
random.shuffle(a, func)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are feeding the shuffled list to be shuffled AGAIN, so the initial conditions aren't the same.  If you run the app again, you will see the same results.  Notice that 'good' (the second element) ends up first.  In the second one, 'b' (the second element) ends up first.

Answer (score 0):

`shuffle` still goes through the list, choosing items to swap, its just that its not random any more. You could do

```
def func():
    return .99999
```

to get no shuffle. This is only because of an accident of implementation. No guarantee that it will always behave that way.